# Progress bar activity is not starting when clicking on the button in android

Tags: android

I have written a following code inside a method which is called on clicking on button:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);  
        progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading files…");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int whichButton)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int whichButton)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
                    try {
                        //---simulate doing something lengthy---
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        //---update the dialog---
                        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy((int)(100/20));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {                   
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

When I click on the button, the progress bar doesn't start.

Comment: Ok this is your part where you create your progress dialog, but how to you call and display this dialog? Maybe you have a problem there. On the first glance this looks legit.

Answer (score 1):

two things

1. you need to call show on your ProgressDialog instance otherwise it will never be shown
2. progressDialog.incrementProgressBy((int)(100/20)); has to run on the UI Thread otherwise you will get the `CalledFromWrongTreadException`

to overcome point 2 you can use an `Handler` or `runOnUiThread`